# Intermittent Bad Gateway (502 error) in a WCF Service

Tags: wcf

Does anyone knows which scenarios a intermittent Bad Gateway can happens?

My client service works fine, so suddenly.. bad gateway!

My current binding:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ReceptorBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="6291456" openTimeout="00:30:00"
             closeTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" useDefaultWebProxy="true" >
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

The log:

```
2013-12-09 09:42:49,659 [12] INFO  - Sending package 1/616.
2013-12-09 09:47:07,025 [12] INFO  - Sending package 2/616.
2013-12-09 09:50:43,510 [12] INFO  - Sending package 3/616.
2013-12-09 09:55:33,195 [12] INFO  - Sending package 4/616.
2013-12-09 09:58:41,370 [12] ERROR - [...]
```

The error:

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (502) Proxy Error. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory'1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory'1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory'1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder'1.RequestClientReliableChannelBinder`1.OnRequest(TRequestChannel channel, Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder'1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder'1.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings'1.SecurityRequestSessionChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Infraero.TINE3.STTComum.Modelo.Contratos.IContratoServicoReceptor.EnviarBilhetes(ContratoDadosReceptor dados)
   at Infraero.TINE3.STTColetor.Negocio.Proxies.ProxyReceptor.EnviarBilhetes(ContratoDadosReceptor dados) in D:\SVN\STT na SEDE\3-0_CodigoFonte_Coletor\3-4_SRC\Coletor 2.0\Infraero.TINE3.STTColetor.Negocio\Proxies\ProxyReceptor.cs:line 34
   at Infraero.TINE3.STTColetor.Negocio.Servicos.ServicoTransmissao.TransmitirBilhetes(ProxyReceptor proxyEnterprise, Int32 quantidadeLotes, Int32 i) in D:\SVN\STT na SEDE\3-0_CodigoFonte_Coletor\3-4_SRC\Coletor 2.0\Infraero.TINE3.STTColetor.Negocio\Servicos\ServicoTransmissao.cs:line 122
   at Infraero.TINE3.STTColetor.Negocio.Servicos.ServicoTransmissao.TransmitirBilhetes() in D:\SVN\STT na SEDE\3-0_CodigoFonte_Coletor\3-4_SRC\Coletor 2.0\Infraero.TINE3.STTColetor.Negocio\Servicos\ServicoTransmissao.cs:line 55
```

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84551e45-19a2-4d0d-bcc0-516a4041943d/explaination-of-different-timeout-types?forum=wcf

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ see my new post edit...